# Two-line clipping bug on HTC EVO Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, listview

We are developing and Android app that uses ListView.  On one of our phones, an HTC EVO (Sprint network) with Android 2.3.3, we are seeing unusual behavior with ListView.  Specifically, text is being clipped after two lines.

We are unable to reproduce this bug on any other phone, tablet or emulator.

Here is an image showing the clipping.  The user entered four lines of text and the ListView displays only the first two: [HTC EVO BUG](http://www.alicebot.org/images/HTCEVOBUG.jpg)

To ensure that it wasn't just our app causing the bug, we tested it with API Demos.
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.hmh.api&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5obWguYXBpIl0.

Has anyone else seen this ListView bug before?  Any ideas what we can try?

Comment: I can confirm that it's shown up on more than one HTC EVO.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong its not the ListView Bug.

I got the same problem of clipping of text, That was because of different Row Height.

So to make the Row Height Unequal I have gave layout_height="wrap_content" in the Top level layout of the Row Layout.

I hope this would be the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem some time ago.
after trying a lot,i got this solution for my application.

problem was in this code :

```
myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyListActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,new String[]{"aaa","bbb","ccc"}));
```

this code works properly in other phone like sony,samsung or etc.
but i saw problem was only in my htc phone(HTC Salsa C510e).

then i just change little in code :

```
myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyListActivity.this, android.R.layout.test_list_item,new String[]{"aaa","bbb","ccc"}));
```

and more then two lines can be seen in a single list.

Hope this will work 4 u...

Answer (score -1):

Looks interesting, my guess will be that some how the TextView have some maxHeight property that not aloud him to extends for more then two lines. This can be simply tested in debug mode, just look at that view component inside your ListView and try to understand what is blocking him, I bet your answer will be there.